# Is there a way to create a measure that is based on specific columns and measure output?

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, measure

I have a dataset which has alarm IDs, the time, date, area and type. I would like a count of how many alarms escalated from low to high and how many didn't.

The expected output from this data set is:

1. Count of alarms that escalated = 1 (ID number 001)
2. Count of alarms that did not escalate = 1 (ID number 002)

I have created multiple measures which show whether the alarm escalated (we'll call those all 'escalated') but these all only work when the table columns are ID numbers and escalated. All escalated measures have resulted in count of alarms that did not escalate = 2. I think this is because ID number 001 has a low and high result so both are counted for 001.

Any ideas would be really applicated!

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wimmS.png)

Comment: In Power Query, group by ID and then check each subtable for a change from low to high.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld I am looking for this to be on a dashboard and so I'm trying to avoid a manual count

Comment: Did you misunderstand my suggestion?  I am not recommending a manual count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved by creating a new table using

Alarm escalation =
SUMMARIZE(
Sheet1,Sheet1[Area],"Escalation",
DISTINCTCOUNT(
Sheet1[Alarm type]
)
)

This allowed me to see a count of 2 of any area that had more than one alarm type and therefore escalation.